# How to detect if a process is running using Python on Win and MAC

Tags: python, process

I am trying to find out a way to detect if a process is running in Windows Task Manager for Windows OS and Macintosh Activity Monitor for MAC OS using Python

Can someone please help me out with the code please?

Comment: Here's how to get running processes on Windows: http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/cookbook.html#list-all-running-processes -- and here's how to get running process info on OSX: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673874/how-can-i-get-the-full-list-of-running-processes-on-a-mac-from-a-python-app

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) is a cross-platform library that retrieves information about running processes and system utilization.

```python
import psutil

pythons_psutil = []
for p in psutil.process_iter():
    try:
        if p.name() == 'python.exe':
            pythons_psutil.append(p)
    except psutil.Error:
        pass
```

```
>>> pythons_psutil
[<psutil.Process(pid=16988, name='python.exe') at 25793424>]

>>> print(*sorted(pythons_psutil[0].as_dict()), sep='\n')
cmdline
connections
cpu_affinity
cpu_percent
cpu_times
create_time
cwd
exe
io_counters
ionice
memory_info
memory_info_ex
memory_maps
memory_percent
name
nice
num_ctx_switches
num_handles
num_threads
open_files
pid
ppid
status
threads
username

>>> pythons_psutil[0].memory_info()
pmem(rss=12304384, vms=8912896)
```

---

In a stock Windows Python you can use `subprocess` and `csv` to parse the output of `tasklist.exe`:

```python
import subprocess
import csv

p_tasklist = subprocess.Popen('tasklist.exe /fo csv',
                              stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                              universal_newlines=True)

pythons_tasklist = []
for p in csv.DictReader(p_tasklist.stdout):
    if p['Image Name'] == 'python.exe':
        pythons_tasklist.append(p)
```

```
>>> print(*sorted(pythons_tasklist[0]), sep='\n')
Image Name
Mem Usage
PID
Session Name
Session#

>>> pythons_tasklist[0]['Mem Usage']
'11,876 K'
```

Comment: Can i do this using only Python(os/subprocess/any other module) and without using any external module

Comment: @jake77, this answer doesn't call `get_pid_list`, and never called it. Originally I used `get_process_list`, but that's no longer available in newer versions of psutil, so last year I updated the answer to use `process_iter`. This works fine in psutil 3.2.2.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a spin off of eryksun's Windows specific solution (using only built-in python modules) dropping the csv import and directly filtering tasklist output for an exe name:

```
import subprocess

def isWindowsProcessRunning( exeName ):                    
    process = subprocess.Popen( 
        'tasklist.exe /FO CSV /FI "IMAGENAME eq %s"' % exeName,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        universal_newlines=True )
    out, err = process.communicate()    
    try   : return out.split("\n")[1].startswith('"%s"' % exeName)
    except: return False
```

Comment: Wrap `out, err = process.communicate()` in a `with process:` to avoid `ResourceWarning`s, borken pipe exceptions, etc. Replace `except:` with `except IndexError` to catch only the index error that indicates `isWindowsProcessRunning` should return `False`. This avoids spurious suppression of `KeyboardInterrupt`, `SystemExit`, or programming error exceptions.

Comment: This function is too fast and too predictable in the result to worry about something like trying to respect a keyboard interrupt in the middle of it, or trying to improve debugging of a syntax error in the one line command... The suggestions aren't "wrong", but are academic overkill.  Also you are favoring suppressing some exceptions in one breath, and exposing others in another?

Comment: In my use of this, I originally didn't wrap `communicate()` with `with process:`, but the `ResourceWarnings` clogged up my test log, making it hard to find important warnings/output. Suppressing `IndexError` makes sense because it's not actually an error, but rather an answer to the original question: is windows process running with name `exeName`? `IndexError` means "no". Other exceptions are actually exceptional and should be propagated to the caller.