# Check if PID exists on Windows with Python without requiring libraries

Tags: python, windows

Is there a way to check if a PID exists on Windows with Python without requiring libraries? How to?

Comment: by libraries you mean any (including python standard library) or just external ones?

Comment: By libraries I mean any relatively big piece of code I would have to include with my project or add to the list of dependencies (to install with `easy_install`, `pip` or whatever)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if pid is not in use in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/568271/check-if-pid-is-not-in-use-in-python)

Comment: it could be as easy as `psutil.pid_exists(pid)` ...

Comment: If psutil was in standard library.

Comment: I just wanted you to wish for it. Otherwise I had put it as an answer.

Comment: For a wish, I would prefer not to bear with Windows at all.

Comment: Related: [How to detect if a process is running using Python on Win and MAC](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8135899/95735)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is solved with a little cup of WINAPI.

```
def pid_running(pid):
    import ctypes
    kernel32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32
    SYNCHRONIZE = 0x100000

    process = kernel32.OpenProcess(SYNCHRONIZE, 0, pid)
    if process != 0:
        kernel32.CloseHandle(process)
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Could you specify OS version and architecture?

Comment: Windows 8.1, x64.  I think you need to check the exit result with a second API call AFTER the open process for this technique to work reliably on all versions of Windows.

Comment: It seems it works as long as it's running with the same user as the checked process.

Comment: Hm. I'm running from an elevated command prompt in win8.1, which then launches python, which then runs a subprocess, yet it doesn't work.

Comment: If you are launching a subprocess, wouldn't it be more reliable to use `.poll()` instead? PIDs can be recycled.

Answer (score 1):

This works on my system..

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> out = subprocess.check_output(["tasklist","/fi","PID eq 1234"]).strip()
>>> if out == "INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria.":
...   print "No such PID :D"
...
No such PID :D
```

Comment: But won't work for anyone whose Windows is not set with English locale.