# Check if process is running in Windows using only Python built-in modules

Tags: python, windows, process

I know that there are a couple of ways to complete that task using `psutil` or `win32ui` modules. But I wonder if there's an option to do that using Python **built-in modules only**? I have also found this question:

[Check if PID exists on Windows with Python without requiring libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17620833/1119381)

But in this case the object is located by `PID` and I want to do it using process name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without PyWin32, you're going to have to go at it the hard way and use Python's [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) module. Fortunately, there is already a post about this here on StackOverflow:

- [How can I find a process by name and kill using ctypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980246/how-can-i-find-a-process-by-name-and-kill-using-ctypes)

You might also find this article useful for getting a list of the running processes:

- http://code.activestate.com/recipes/305279-getting-process-information-on-windows/

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this will help you:

```
import subprocess

s = subprocess.check_output('tasklist', shell=True)
if "cmd.exe" in s:
    print s
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you're trying to do is test whether a process is running by its process name, you could just import the check_output method from the subprocess module (not the entire module):

```
from subprocess import check_output

print('Test whether a named process appears in the task list.\n')
processname = input('Enter process name: ')   # or just assign a specific process name to the processname variable 
tasks = check_output('tasklist')
if processname in str(tasks):
    print('{} is in the task list.'.format(processname))
else:
    print('{} not found.'.format(processname))
```

Output:

```
>>> Discord.exe
Discord.exe is in the task list.

>>> NotARealProcess.exe
NotARealProcess.exe not found.
```

(This works for me on Windows 10 using Python 3.10.)  Note that since this is just searching for a specific string across the entire task list output, it will give false positives on partial process names (such as "app.exe" or "app" if "myapp.exe" is running) and other non-process text input that happens to be in the task list:

```
>>> cord.ex
cord.ex is in the task list.

>>> PID Session Name
PID Session Name is in the task list.
```

This code generally should work fine if you just want to find a known process name in the task list and are searching by the whole name, but for more rigorous uses, you might want to use a more complex approach like parsing the task list into a dictionary and separating out the names for more focused searching, as well as add some error checking to handle edge cases.