# Launch a video, and if it is closed, launch it again

Tags: python

What happens, is instead of doing what I want, it will restart the program after the 4 second sleep, ann the module check_process does is checks if the process is open and returns either 1 for open or 0 for closed, but I just can't figure out why it won't move from the if loop to the else loop when the conditions are satisfied, if anyone could help me, that'd be great, thanks!

```
import os
import time
import check_process
c = 5
global isProcessFound
isProcessFound = 0
while c == 5:
    check_process.check("wmplayer.exe")
    if isProcessFound == 0:
        os.startfile("C:\\Users\\Kevin\\Desktop\\PYTUT.mp4")
        time.sleep(4)
    else:
        time.sleep(3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find any information on the check_process module that you import, but I found this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135899/how-to-detect-if-a-process-is-running-using-python-on-win-and-mac) that you could use. This would give you something like:

```
import psutil  # From https://code.google.com/p/psutil/

def is_running(process_name):
    return process_name in psutil.get_process_list()
```

But looking at your code, the problem seems to be that you never update `c` and `isProcessFound`, so I don't understand how your program could terminate or do anything else than start your video and sleep for 4 seconds. Maybe you just need to write:

```
isProcessFound = check_process.check("wmplayer.exe")
```

and update `c` when you want the program to close?

Comment: I got it, I finally just ended up using                                        import os
    import time
    global a
    c = 5
    while c == 5:
     w = "wmplayer.exe"
     o = os.popen("tasklist.exe").read()
     if w in o:
      time.sleep(5)
     else:
      os.startfile("C:\\Users\\Kevin\\Desktop\\PYTUT.mp4")       It would help if I could figure out how to format that right in a comment >.<

Comment: @user3179485: If your comment is an answer to your question, you should post it as a seperate answer. Otherwise you could use ` to format code.