# Python - validate if the process filtered by PID is still running

Tags: python, subprocess

Using subprocess library I do spawn new processes.

```py
import subprocess
pid = subprocess.Popen(["sleep", "1"]).pid
is_process_running(pid)
```

The whole point of that is to invoke a script in an async wait and continue work of the program.
I do not want to spawn multiple subprocesses with the same script invoked, that is why I am trying to detect if the process with a given PID number still exists in the system.

The function that I use looks in the following way:

```py
import os
def is_process_running(process_id):
    try:
        os.kill(process_id, 0)
        return True
    except OSError:
        return False
```

Unfortunately, processes created with subprocess library are accessible forever. The status that these have is: **defunct**. Due to that, the function that I have written above always returns **True**. Is there any way to detect if the process is marked with **defunct**?

Comment: Related question: [How to detect if a process is running using Python on Win and MAC - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135899/how-to-detect-if-a-process-is-running-using-python-on-win-and-mac#comment54164756_8136371)

Answer (score 0):

It's much simpler to keep and operate on the `Popen` instance returned by the `subprocess.Popen` call. This does what you want:

```
import subprocess as sp
import time

def is_process_running(proc):
    return proc.poll() is None

proc = sp.Popen(['sleep', '10'])
is_process_running(proc) # will return True
time.sleep(6)
is_process_running(proc) # still True
time.sleep(6)
is_process_running(proc) # will now return False
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the case is that I wanted to store PID value in the DB, and access it using different python workers. I cant keep it as a variable

Comment: Then in that case, look at the [`psutil` package](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/). It has lots of good utilities for managing processes, including querying they're state and sending signals.

Comment: For example: [this](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.pid_exists) should solve your problem exactly.